# Genetic Algorithm: Grouping students without knowing exact number of groups

Tags: grouping, genetic-algorithm

I have students with defined levels. Some of the students are in the groups from previous week, some of them are new. Students from previous week should be kept in their groups.
Group has a level which is calculated by the average of containing student's levels. New student can be added to the group if difference of student level and group level is less than defined limit(for example 3). There is also minimum and maximum group sizes. If there is no enough space in the group we should create new one. 
I have tried to solve with clustering algorithms(hierarchical and non hierarchical) but non of them works for my case.
I need to create minimum amount of groups.

I would like to know will genetic algorithm work . The genes of a chromosome would represent a single student and their assignment to a class. Fitness function part will use all constraints(max group size, min group size).
As I understood for applying genetic algorithm I need to know groups count which is not clear in my case. Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "best way of initial population"?  This sounds like a request for some system design (off-topic).

Comment: We need to you fully define the problem, and what you've done to develop an algorithm so far.  What determines whether a new student joins a particular group?  What can force formation of a new group?  What evaluation determines the best grouping?

Comment: I have edited it.

Comment: There is no evaluation which will determine best grouping. We should have as minimum amount of groups as we can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, genetic algorithm can work.  I'm not sure where you get the idea that you have to know the quantity of groups.  All a genetic algorithm needs is a generator for making children, a fitness function to judge which children are the best, and a few quantity parameters (how many to keep as parents for the next generation, how many children to produce, ... things that are in the generator).

I suggest that your individuals ("chromosomes") be a list of the groups for the new generation.  To save time, your generator should yield only viable children: those that fulfill the group-size requirements.  Any child that does not satisfy those should be skipped and replaced.

The main work in this scenario is setting up a generator that knows how to split groups: when you find that a new student requires a new group, then you have to draw `min_group_size`-1 students from other groups.  If you have the entire population of new students at once, then you can make global decisions, instead.

Is this enough to move you in a useful direction?

---

**Update per user comment:**

- You cannot guarantee finding the optimal answer with a genetic algorithm.
- The number of chromosomes depends on what works best for you.  You need to handle a variety of possible group assignments, as well as new groups.  Here is where you have to experiment; welcome to machine learning.

I would start investigating with a "comfortable" number of chromosomes, perhaps the quantity of groups times sqrt(quantity of new students).  Depending on time constraints, I'd think that somewhere from 20 to 200 chromosomes would be good for you.  Your critical measures of success are how often it finds a great solution, and how much time you spend finding it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer , yes it helps me a lot . One more question. So in this case how many chromosomes should I create initially ? To be sure to find best solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It gives me clear understanding of some parts.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, forming students groups can be done with the help of optimization. Genetic Algorithm (GA) is not the only one optimization algorithm that has been applied to the specific problem, but also Particle Swarm Optimization (PSO). In a recent research, a PSO was implemented to classify students under unknown number of groups. PSO showed improved capabilities compared to GA. I think that all you need is the specific research.

The paper is: Forming automatic groups of learners using particle swarm optimization for applications of differentiated instruction

You can find the paper here: https://doi.org/10.1002/cae.22191

Perhaps the researchers could guide you through researchgate: 
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/338078753

As I can see, the researchers used the characteristics of each cluster as a solution vector (chromosomes) combined with a threshold number determining the number of groups (very interesting - I think this is exactly what you need).

I hope I have helped you